# Servidor Apache

Tags: apache

Felicitações a todos. Estou iniciando na aventura de programação. Estou com dúvida em compreender a diferença entre um servidor de hospedagem e o servidor apache. Por quê o servidor de hospedagem que já é um servidor precisa rodar apache? Grato.

Comment: O que faz um "servidor de hospedagem" ser um servidor de hospedagem?

Comment: Um servidor de Hospedagem é uma máquina física onde é atribuído um IP a ela, para poder ser encontrada na Internet, o Apache é um software que tona possível o tráfego das informações sob o protocolo http. Tipo assim...